# Where should I put my question mark in Swift?

Tags: swift

I can see in the Apple documentation, when `if let`, the `?` is used after `as`. But I tried this and the compile would not complain and the code behaved the same as `as? NSError`. So is this acceptable in Swift (not standard though), and if it is, is there any difference?

```swift
if let error = error as NSError? { ...
```

when it comes to

```swift
var arr = [Int8?]()        
arr.append(29 as Int8?)
arr.append(1 as? Int8) // warning: Conditional downcast from literal to 'Int8' always fails; consider using 'as' coercion
```

Why in this case the downcasting will always fails?

Comment: When you put the ? after the type it means that the value is declare d to be optional (no cast is done), when you put it after `as` it means cast the value if possible otherwise return nil

Comment: I think you're confusing `as`/`as?`/`as!` with C-style casting (e.g. `(char) someInt`). In Swift, `as` and its variants do not changes the type of the value at runtime (with some exceptions about Objective-C interop when Foundation is imported, but I'll ignore those). What these operators do is make runtime type-checks, which if successful, lead to the same value being referenced by a different static type. To actually convert the value from one integer type to another, you would use the respective initalizers, like `UInt8(someInt)`.

Comment: I'm reopening this, because I don't think the linked question was correct. It was about using `as?` to unwrap optionals, where as this question actually involves no optional unwrapping at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the purposes of most of this answer, I'll ignore the bridging features Swift has for inter-operating with Objective-C (when `Foundation` is imported).

---

### re: `arr.append(29 as Int8?)`

`as` works just like a type annotation. No values are changed, you're just giving extra type information to the compiler, so `arr.append(29 as Int8?)` works as if you had written:

```
var arr = [Int8?]()
let i: Int8? = 29
arr.append(i)
```

However, the compiler already knows that `arr` is an `[Int8?]` (a.k.a. `Array<Optional<Int8>>`), whose `Element` type is `Int8?`. As a result, it already knows that the argument to `append` needs to be an `Int8?`. This, coupled with the fact that Swift can automatically promote a non-optional value (e.g. `Int8`) into an optional value (`Int8?`) when that's useful, you could just write:

```
arr.append(29)
```

### re: `arr.append(1 as? Int8)`

This snippet needs a bit more explanation. You see, `1` is not an `Int` in Swift, although it can be.

It's an *integer literal*, which can be used to initialize a value of any type that conforms to [`ExpressibleByIntegerLiteral`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/expressiblebyintegerliteral).

The fact that above you're able to write `let i: Int8? = 29` instead of `let i: Int8? = Int8(29)` comes as a direct consequence; `Int8` conforms to `ExpressibleByIntegerLiteral` (as does `Float`, `Double`, and every other signed and unsigned integer type).

The compiler will use contextual type information to pick what the best `ExpressibleByIntegerLiteral`-conforming type a given integer literal should be. This could come from several places:

1. An explicit type annotation, like `let i: Int8 = 123`
2. Using `as`, like `let i = 123 as Int8`
3. Returning from a function with a known return type, such as:

   ```swift
   func returnsInt8() -> Int8 {
       return 123 // We know this must be Int8 from the return type
   }
   ```
4. Passing as an argument to a parameter with a known type, such as:

   ```swift
   func takesAnInt8(_: Int8) {}
   takesAnInt8(123) // This argument can fit the parameter's type if it's Int8
   ```

In the absence of any of this type contextual information, the compiler will default to initializing literals into `IntegerLiteralType`, which is `Int` by default.

So when you write: `1 as? Int8`, it's as if you wrote:

```swift
let i = 1 // (this is an `Int`)
arr.append(i as? Int8)
```

The problem becomes clear: `i` is statically typed to an `Int`, and there no scenario in which `Int` is an `Int8`, so this cast will always fail.

### re: `error as NSError?`

This works because you have `Foundation` imported, which introduces some magical bridging that's intended to make interoperation with Objective C. For example, you can do:

```swift
let aSwiftString: Swift.String = "abc"
someObjCApi(aSwiftString as NSString) // Now it's a `Foundation.NSString`
```

Which will cause the runtime value to be bridged. As you saw, you can also bridge from `Swift.Error` to `NSError` (and from `Swift.Error?` to `NSError?`). This complicates the language a bit, because it means that the explanation of "`as` only does static type annotation with no runtime effect" is no longer true.